# CSS Grid Layout позицинирование блоков

Tags: css

подскажите как сделать так, чтобы некоторые элементы занимали несколько ячеек, но количество ячеек заранее неизвестно, так как адаптивно?

Сейчас я использую:

```css
.SettingsContent > div:nth-child(2){
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 8 / 9;
}
```

Но этот код едет, когда количество строк меняется(нижний элемент едет)

Вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем примере ничего не едет.

Comment: Я же написал в кавычках, что последний хочу задать двойным, и когда я это делаю верстка едет, уберите минус пожалуйста

Comment: Извиняюсь, не прав забыл задать картинки, сейчас

Comment: Тут нужно добавить [repro], а не картинки (последние можно оставить как пояснение, но они не должны заменять собой пример).